# What determines the path in radioactive decay series?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity, binding-energy

How an element decays can be plotted in a diagram like this:

[image]

source: https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/City_College_of_San_Francisco/Chemistry_101B/10%3A_Nuclear_Chemistry/10.3%3A_Radioactive_Decay

What determines the path taken of uranium? Since in quantum mechanics the resultant path can be seen as a 'superposition' of paths, is this also de case for radioactive decay?

EDIT: why is this path not possible?

[image]

Comment: but there is only one path, so it has nothing with which to  superimpose. But if there is a series with more than one way to get to the same final state...that would be really interesting if it were coherent, or trivial if it were incoherent. . Not sure.

Comment: Information on various decays can be found through the ENSDF database (e.g. the BNL mirror: https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/). Binding energies are most easily found through the Atomic Mass Evaluation 2020 (Google finds it easily). An unforced decay cannot take place if it does not release energy (see AME), and if multiple paths can result in energy release than exactly how often each occurs can be found in ENSDF.

Answer (score 1):

Some isotopes have only one possible decay mode; some have several. The first few steps in this $^{238}\text U$ decay path are fixed, up to $^{226}\text{Ra}$. But as well as decaying to $^{222}\text{Rn}$ by emitting an alpha particle, $^{226}\text{Ra}$ has two alternative decay modes - it can decay to $^{226}\text{Th}$ by emitting two beta particles, or it can split into $^{212}\text{Pb}$ and $^{14}\text C$. These alternative decay modes are much rarer than the alpha decay mode, but which one happens for a particular nucleus is a matter of chance. By collecting enough data we can empirically measure the relative probabilities of different decay modes, but we can't predict which one will occur for a particular nucleus.

The other variable, of course, is the time taken for each decay to happen. There is a $50 \%$ probability that each decay will happen within a given period, called its half-life, but the exact timing of the decay for a particular nucleus is again a matter of chance.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer one of your questions in a general sort of way here.

For any element heavier than ~iron, the amount of energy released in decay exceeds the binding energy holding the nucleus together and so there will be a tendency for spontaneous decay to occur as the atom strives for an energy minimum. This means uranium "wants" to travel generally down and left on that chart towards the most comfortable spot at iron 56.

For each different isotope/nucleus in this chart, there will be a specific *binding energy* (trying to hold the whole shebang together), a specific *activation energy* (required to kick the nucleus over the hump and thence into action), and a net energy difference between it and its nearest neighbors "down" on the chart. The interplay between these factors will determine how likely a certain decay path will be, what the associated half-life will be, and whether the decay particle will be an alpha or a beta and how big a gamma release might be.

This is a complicated business which will involve other stuff I have not mentioned here- like, for example, the fact that on this chart there are several "magic spots" where the particular occupant of that spot is particularly happy (i.e., stable) and other decay paths that are "locked out" and unavailable to the unstable nucleus.

The sum of all these considerations at every possible step in the decay chain is what causes all those zigs and zags in the overall chain.

Comment: Yes I understand that the reason the path is chosen is because the binding energies of the next atom is favourable. This binding energy is empirical number, I am asking why it chooses this path and not another? Can it shortly decay in an unfavourable atom if the next decay is ultimately favourable?